# MacTex Vs TexLive Installation

Tags: texlive, installing, mactex

I have downloaded TexLive 2015 DVD, and it appears that Linux Commands can be used to install TexLive.

I went to the TexLive website, and they suggest using the MacTex Distribution which agains is a 2 GB + download.

Would it be safe to install from the TeXLive DVD on a MAC?

Comment: It is the same installation. MacTeX is just TeX Live packaged to make it easier for Mac users to install (actually once downloaded, it is probably the easiest TeX live installation compared to Linux and Windows)

Comment: I even install TeXLive directly to Windows 10, since I don't like MikTeX & C... It is the best distribution for every modern platform. MacTeX adds some pieces of software like TeXShop and others, but the engine is TeXLive.

Comment: @daleif Would it be prudent to use, the Linux Commands in the Mac OSX Terminal to install it then?

Comment: @Indian, not really. It might not setup the `texbin` stuff, and you might need to add the path manually. But if you know what you are doing, then there should not be any problems

Comment: If you are installing from the DVD, then remember to update it afterwards.